# Running the application on emulator doesn't show up as the XML design page in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[As us can see guys there is a difference and I don't know why it occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqvKz.png)

I've added the horizontal and vertical also that's not the problem I don't know what it is

Here is my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fghdfhdfhdfghdfgh"
    tools:context=".Screen1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="496dp"
        android:background="@drawable/b2111"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="496dp"
        android:background="@drawable/b111"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using constraint layout and your design in XML has bigger screen size than your emulator. Have you tried using other emulator device with bigger screen? Or maybe you can provide your XML codes.

Comment: Try to change your top margin for both of your button and see if it works.

Comment: If I changed them they'll go up for sure but the question is why it's not showing in the emulator as the design screen

Comment: Instead of using top margin, use the bottom margin instead, because if your screen is 200px, and your top margin is 225px, of course the button will be cut off. But if you use bottom margin, it wont happen.

Comment: Still, the same error may be the background-size is not fit? What background-size should I use for the pixel 3xl??

Comment: I am pretty sure the background has nothing to do with it. I had the same problem before and all I did was delete the top margin and change it to bottom margin (because with constraint layout you need to constrain any element to at least 1 vertical and horizontal margin).

Comment: I know I did that and got the same error just look at the pic it's shrinked